# How to get the timeout of the Forms authentication from a client connecting through Client Application Services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have an ASP.NET website configured with

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="10080">
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

and a WinForm app using Client Application Services for login. How can I find the "timeout" parameter from the WinForm app?

---

Also check:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AccessingTheASPNETFormsAuthenticationTimeoutValue.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember if the cookie that ASP.NET sets as part of forms authentication has it's expiration date set to conicide with the actual session inactivity expiration, but if so, I believe this will be your only way to find out: have your client app subtract the current dateTime from the cookie's expiration date.